# expanded row group to remain expanded after row data is reloaded

Tags: react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using React with Redux to show a ag-grid table in a particular page.
I have a AgGridReact tag in a page. rowData is grouped and loaded dynamically from a state created in Reducer.

My requirement is if the group is expanded it should remain expanded even after rowData is changed. As of now after my rowData is updated all the rows gets collapse.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve this by setting this property to true in gridOptions

```
rememberGroupStateWhenNewData = true
```

As per official docs-

> **rememberGroupStateWhenNewData**
>    When true, if you set new data into the
>   grid and have groups open, the grid will keep groups open if they
>   exist in the new dataset. See [Keeping Group State](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#keeping-group-state).

Here is an [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#keeping-group-state)

Comment: I don't see `rememberGroupStateWhenNewData` anywhere on that page.  They must have updated the version/docs.  Do you know how to do this in the latest version?

Comment: @user2023861 according to a comment in their code, I think that function has been deprecated.  It says `/** @deprecated - no longer needed, transaction updates keep group state */
    rememberGroupStateWhenNewData?: boolean;`